# nested exception is javax.jms.InvalidDestinationException: Unknown destination type - $Proxy115

Tags: java, jms, spring-jms

I get this exception when i try to send a message to queue. My jms properties are set via spring application-context.Please find the applicationContext.xml properties set for the jms.

```
        <bean id="jmsQueueConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiTemplate">
        <ref bean="jndiTemplate" />
    </property>
    <property name="lookupOnStartup" value="false"/>
    <property name="jndiName">
        <value>${jmsQueueConnectionFactory.jndiName}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="proxyInterface" value="javax.jms.ConnectionFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
    <property name="environment">
        <props>
            <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">
                ${jndiTemplate.naming.factory}
            </prop>
            <prop key="com.sonicsw.jndi.mfcontext.domain">
                ${jndiTemplate.domain}
            </prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">
                ${jndiTemplate.provider.url}
            </prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.security.principal">${jndiTemplate.security.principal}</prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.security.credentials">${jndiTemplate.security.credentials}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="requestsQueue" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiTemplate">
        <ref bean="jndiTemplate" />
    </property>
    <property name="lookupOnStartup" value="false"/>
    <property name="jndiName">
        <value>${requestsQueue.jndiName}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="proxyInterface" value="javax.jms.Destination"/>
</bean>
```

Am getting the exception as below:

```
   org.springframework.jms.InvalidDestinationException: Unknown destination type - $Proxy115; nested exception is javax.jms.InvalidDestinationException: Unknown destination type - $Proxy115
```

Comment: Please post full stack trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it happens because you hide your `requestsQueue` behind a lazy proxy, and your JMS implementation doesn't like it for some reason:

```
<property name="lookupOnStartup" value="false"/>
<property name="proxyInterface" value="javax.jms.Destination"/>
```

Try to remove these lines.

Comment: vow...you are amazing..After removing that..it worked for me..Thanks a million.